# How to do a type alias reassignment in typescript without intermediate variables?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following contrived example:

```js
type Response = {
  data: {
    bar: number;
  }
}

type MyData = {
  bar: number;
}

const responses: Response[] = [/**/];
const data = responses
  .map(response => response.data);
```

Now if you'd hover over `data` in your IDE, it'll tell you that its type is `{ bar: number }[]`, and hovering over the `.map` function gives an even more complex (unreadable) type. In real-world cases with more complex types the hover information becomes completely useless, and so do error messages involving these types.

So what I want is a way to tell TS that we want to treat it as a `MyData` type. I.e. I want to achieve the following effect:

```js
const data = responses
  .map(response => {
    const data: MyData = response.data; // errors if response.data doesn't satisfy MyData
    return data; // we're mapping to `MyData`, and not to `{bar : number}`
  });
```

I want this without the unnecessary boilerplate of using an intermediate variable. Ideally, I'd use something like this:

```js
const data = responses
  .map(response => response.data with type MyData);
```

I have a few partial solutions, but none of them work well in real-world scenarios:

#### 1: use `MyData` in the `Response` type

```js
type Response = { data : MyData }
```

This requires that we can change our input type, which isn't always an option. E.g. our response type might be auto-generated, or come from a library.

#### 2: explicitly type our `data` variable:

```js
const data: MyData[] = responses.map(response => response.data);
```

While this makes the type of `data` more useful, it still keeps the original complex type for `.map`. In less contrived examples we might be chaining several operations (`map`/`filter` etc), and all of these will still use the un-aliased type signature.

#### 3: cast with `as`

```js
const data = responses.map(response => response.data as MyData);
```

This is unsafe. If `response.data` changes to `MyData | undefined` then the above code compiles just fine, even though it's broken.

#### 4: cast with `satisfies`

```js
const data = responses.map(response => response.data satisfies MyData);
```

This is safe but doesn't work. It keeps the original type (by design).

#### 5: set the type parameter explicitly

```js
const data = responses.map<MyData>(response => response.data);
```

This works reasonably well for our contrived example, but in real-world scenarios, it doesn't always work. Apart from stylistic concerns, the main issue is that if our operation takes multiple type parameters, we now need to supply ALL parameters. This is not desirable, and sometimes not even feasible.

---

So what I'm looking for is a way to "reassign" the type of a value without using an intermediate variable. Does such a thing exist? How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Response` contains something that coincidentally happens to look like `MyData`, it is not `MyData`. In an ideal world you'd just say `type Response = { data: MyData }` but if you don't have this choice all other options require some explicit casting and are generally unsafe as you have noted. Personally I would prefer `.map<MyData>`

Comment: You can annotate the callback return type [as shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZZxKm).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, that's brilliant! Please do write it up, then I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [annotate the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as follows:

```
const arrowFn = (x: string): number => x.length
// annotation -----------> ^^^^^^^^
```

and thus you can call `responses.map()` like this:

```
const data = responses.map((response): MyData => response.data);
```

Where the type of the `response` parameter has still [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) so that you don't have to annotate it.

---

Note that the annotation goes between the closing parenthesis "`)`" of the parameter list and the arrow "`=>`".  If your function has just one parameter you still need to wrap it in parentheses to have it compile.  That is, you can't do this:

```
const data = responses.map(response: MyData => response.data); // error
```

even though the unannotated return type version works fine without parentheses:

```
const data = responses.map(response => response.data); // okay
```

---

Sadly I can't find what I'd consider "official documentation" of this feature.  The [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/) describes return type annotations for function statements, and the (archived and largely obsolete) [language specification](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ccf3d3c5f9b4bc2883d700870ed2dac454050f1f/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md) doesn't spell this out as obviously as I'd like, even though it has a [section on arrow functions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ccf3d3c5f9b4bc2883d700870ed2dac454050f1f/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#411-arrow-functions).  If someone finds authoritative documentation for this (excluding just the compiler itself or some documentation that uses but does not mention the feature) I'd be happy to link it here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgErQwD2wUEAklAIIBCArgJYYAujwACoBPGMgJEivUZWp0GSALx5CkogBMQvEAC4VatQCMQAJz3AOYQxBMBuVWoC+DpM5fSxSALLCAIlpAlfQNjM2JLazsXNzV4eV4kUxMaAHcAMWAggAoADz0oXhMuYABzAEpzCJslAD4kHIA6DAhS3gALezUAei7E4GAabV4uOiQAWgnJqbG6gD15hfn8ZZc4+gSTOXpoPSpYeQgAbQBdIMOugCoLruP7VfikdQBGIM397agGsBAYLLfaba1JD-A4NTTaMq2JA9JA0ADWIGE93WjwATK8tgxPt9fiDtnofP5tEC8QwwQFIdDejZkiZkQVHgEMe8sV8flk-piIBVvH4mYo6qSIOSIVCYfDEStVM5HEA)